# Rails Engine db connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-engines

If I have a rails engine, and it connects to a different database from my regular app, if I call a class from the regular app within my rails engine, will that query connect to my rails engine database or regular app database?

Answer (score 0):

Without any customisation, it will connect to the database specified in your config/database.yml

Follow here for a good guide on setting up more than 1 DB: https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/